# MySQL PROCEDURE which will insert user into appropriate table

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

i have problem with creating procedure, can someone tell me if i'm going in the right direction?  Please tell me what's wrong.

Thanks for help.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Uzytkownicy(
    idUzytkownika INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    login VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    haslo VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    rola varchar(5)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Administratorzy(
    idUzytkownika INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    login VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    haslo VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    rola varchar(5)
);

CREATE PROCEDURE `ins`
(
    in `P_idUzytkownik` INT,
    in `P_login` varchar(50),
    in `P_haslo` varchar(64),
    in `P_rola` varchar(5)
)
BEGIN
    IF `P_rola` ="Admin"
    THEN
    INSERT INTO `Administratorzy`
    VALUES(`P_idUzytkownik`,`P_login`,`P_haslo`,`P_rola`)
    ELSE 
    INSERT INTO `Uzytkownicy`
    VALUES(`P_idUzytkownik`,`P_login`,`P_haslo`,`P_rola`)
END
```

Comment: Please tell US what's wrong!

Comment: I get this message #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSE 
    INSERT INTO `Uzytkownicy`
    VALUES(`P_idUzytkownik`,`P_login`,`P_h' at line 13

Comment: This is not SQL-SERVER!!!! Please edit your tag. And before asking  see [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you know different between SQL and RDBMS? Why you changed SQL-Server to SQL? Please specify what RDBMS do you use if you wannna help

Comment: Ok, as I see you do not know what RDBMS you use then I say to you: You use MySQL! And you shouldn't say "Please tell me what's wrong." you have to describe what is wrong  and what has been done so far to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html

You are missing some semicolons. Try:

```
IF `P_rola` ="Admin"
THEN
INSERT INTO `Administratorzy`
VALUES(`P_idUzytkownik`,`P_login`,`P_haslo`,`P_rola`);
ELSE 
INSERT INTO `Uzytkownicy`
VALUES(`P_idUzytkownik`,`P_login`,`P_haslo`,`P_rola`);
```

That being said, why not put all of your users into a single table and have a 5th field that holds `Administratorzy` and `Uzytkownicy`? What happens when a user switched from a U to an A. You have to Delete and Insert a record instead of just doing an `UPDATE`. What happens when you have a new type of Role? A new table?